# Only take first value from loop GOLANG

Tags: go

Does anyone know why it took first value when I call variable inside the loop ? I want to make palindrome but the code just like this, can someone explain me. I'm new in GO

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        var kata, kosong, kebalikan, katanya string

    fmt.Print("Kata :")
    fmt.Scan(&kata)
    panjang := len(kata) - 1
    for i := panjang; i >= 0; i-- {
        kebalikan = kosong + fmt.Sprint(string(kata[i]))
        fmt.Print(kebalikan)
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
    for i := 0; i <= panjang; i++ {
        katanya = kosong + fmt.Sprint(string(kata[i]))
        fmt.Print(katanya)
    }
    fmt.Println(katanya)
    fmt.Println(kebalikan)
    if fmt.Sprint(katanya) == fmt.Sprint(kebalikan) {
        fmt.Println(true)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your greater than and less than symbols the wrong way around. `i >= 0` checks for when I is greater than or equal to 0, which it will be from the start because you're setting i to the length of that string.

Comment: can u give me example sir

Answer (score 0):

i have my answer from my own question, here i mean

```
var kata, kebalikan string

fmt.Print("Kata :")
fmt.Scan(&kata)
panjang := len(kata) - 1
for i := panjang; i >= 0; i-- {
    kebalikan = kebalikan + fmt.Sprint(string(kata[i]))
}
if fmt.Sprint(kata) == fmt.Sprint(kebalikan) {
    fmt.Println(true)
} else {
    fmt.Println(false)
}
```